# What's the difference here between the source codes of Python3.5 and Python3.6?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-internals

```
 testing on ../../test/test_patm.py
python: Python/compile.c:4420: int assemble_lnotab(struct assembler *, 
struct instr *): Assertion `d_lineno >= 0' failed.
Aborted
```

When running my test programs I got an error as given above.
Finally I found it was just quite few differences between the source codes of Python3.5 and Python3.6.
Just one line:

Python3.5

```
static int
assemble_lnotab(struct assembler *a, struct instr *i)
{
  int d_bytecode, d_lineno;
  Py_ssize_t len;
  unsigned char *lnotab;

  d_bytecode = a->a_offset - a->a_lineno_off;
  d_lineno = i->i_lineno - a->a_lineno;

  assert(d_bytecode >= 0);
  assert(d_lineno >= 0);   // the only difference

  if(d_bytecode == 0 && d_lineno == 0)
      return 1;
  ...
```

Python 3.6

```
static int
assemble_lnotab(struct assembler *a, struct instr *i)
{
    int d_bytecode, d_lineno;
    Py_ssize_t len;
    unsigned char *lnotab;

    d_bytecode = (a->a_offset - a->a_lineno_off) * sizeof(_Py_CODEUNIT);
    d_lineno = i->i_lineno - a->a_lineno;

    assert(d_bytecode >= 0);

    if(d_bytecode == 0 && d_lineno == 0)
        return 1;
```

What if I just deleted `assert(d_lineno >= 0);`?

Comment: I see another difference, `d_bytecode` is multiplied by `sizeof(_Py_CODEUNIT)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is the definition of it.

`typedef uint16_t _Py_CODEUNIT;`

Comment: So what is your code, why does it trigger the assertion error? I'd not remove an assertion from Python code, no, it indicates you have a bug *elsewhere*.

Comment: have you tested your program on 3.6 ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why my codes resulted this question is that I didn't change the `lineno` of the ast, it might seem to be incorrect, but it do not lead to any error in Python3.6!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yep, I'm trying to give some new grammars to Python. Firstly I made these works on Python3.6, now I'm to do the same things in Python3.5.

Comment: See https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f3914eb16d28ad9eb20fe5133d9aa83658bcc27f for why the code was changed. Does your use-case need that specific feature? Then you can't use Python 3.5, your code requires 3.6 or newer. Also see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0511/

Comment: According to the [history on github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/master/Python/compile.c#L5041), this code hasn't changed much in years.

Comment: @RolandSmith: it changed in January 2016.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh, thank you! It really helps!(How do you find the key for the problem so quickly?...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yet it doesn't show up in the blame history. Must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @RolandSmith: You can't display *deleted* lines in a blame. And the change does show up in your blame link, just scroll down a little, the *added* lines are right there.

Comment: @misakawa more info in my *answer*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using a *debug* build of 3.5. In Python 3.5 and *any* previous version, the line numbering within a single bytecode block (i.e. the bytecode of a module, or a function) had to be *monotonic*, that is each opcode had to map to a line in source code whose linenumber must be *greater than or equal to* the line number of the *previous* opcode.  This was ever checked in debug builds; in release builds of Python the `assert` would not be compiled in, but the generated line number tab would have been invalid anyway.

This was discussed in [Issue 26107](https://bugs.python.org/issue26107) on [bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org). The requirement of monotonicity of line numbers was seen detrimental to optimizations, many of which would reorganize the generated bytecode around. Thus the check was removed in 3.6 *along with other changes* that make the line number delta be a signed integer.

**You can comment out *this* assert pretty safely, as release builds would have eliminated it anyhow, but don't expect debugging to work correctly in the generated code as the line number tab is now invalid.**

As an alternative, if you're reorganizing lines in the AST, or something similar, you can set *all* line numbers to 0 - not just the missing ones; or you can generate fake line numbers that don't break the monotonicity rule.

---

A coincidental problem occurred with generated ASTs, as the  [`ast.fix_missing_locations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.fix_missing_locations) would write the line number of *0* to any nodes that lacked line numbering. If parts of the AST contain line numbers because they originated from `ast.parse`, it will be likely that the resulting AST tree would break the monotonicity requirement - which again would only lead to problems on non-release builds of Pythons < 3.6.

---

The other change, that is not relevant to the bug here, is the change from bytecode to *wordcode*, which also was introduced in Python 3.6. Here each opcode would be a 16-bit word instead of a 8-bit byte with possible extended args. That's the reason for the offset being multiplied by `sizeof(_Py_CODEUNIT);`.